# How to add a div over another div with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

First, I have this:
[image]

Now, what I want to do is, to make "zoom" of some nodes. Once I double click on some of the nodes, I want to see the whole node on the page:
[image]

Now, because every time I zoom a node - I see the same thing (a big circle), I want to make this: once I double-click on a node - only a new div to be added which will have the circle and it will overlap its container. I am working with [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/), so the circle should be drawn with Raphael.

How should I do this with JavaScript? (adding new div with the circle which will overlap the container, and drawing the circle with Raphael, which shouldn't be hard, but the creation of the div is the part where I am stuck)

What I did so far is:

```
zoomDiv = document.createElement('div');
zoomDiv.id = 'graph-zoom';
zoomDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
zoomDiv.style.zIndex = 2000;
this.container.appendChild(zoomDiv);
```

When I go to the HTML, I can see that the div is added to the container:
[image]

But it is too low. I don't know if this is the problem why I can't see the empty div so far or is it something else?

Comment: Are you just looking for creating a new div or a div with the contents of the zoomed node?

Comment: Only creating a new div. Later I will work with the data which contains the node, but for now, I only need creating a new div like shown on the second image.

Comment: var newDiv = document.createElement("div") - This will give you a new div.Append the element to some parent div and give it a style class that will have a higher z-index so that it will overlap the original node

Comment: I know that, but I need to overlap the container. I did this + adding bigger z-index, but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you want to overlap -  are you not able to position it on the base node or you are not able to show the new div on the top?

Comment: Edited my question, I think that answers your question. Tnx for the efforts you've made so far!

Comment: Now you need to position the div using left and right so that it will overlay on top of the container. Try the below code position the zoomDiv on top of this.container. What you have done so far is to create a absolute position div.
zoomDiv.style.top = this.container.offsetTop + "px";
zoomDiv.style.left = this.container.offsetLeft + "px";

Comment: I did it like @Xotic750 suggested and it worked. Sinduja Ramaraj, thanks a lot for your help, +1 on every comment of yours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example demonstrates the [creation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.createElement) of a `div` in javascript, how to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild) and [remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.removeChild) it to and from the `document.body`, the use of CSS [`position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position)`: absolute;` and CSS [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/z-index) to place elements on top of one another.

CSS

```
#parent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <button id="open">Open</button>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var open = document.getElementById("open");

function addChild() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var close = document.createElement("button");

    div.id = "child";

    close.id = "close";
    close.textContent = "Close";
    close.addEventListener("click", function closeSelf() {
        document.body.removeChild(div);
    }, false);

    div.appendChild(close);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

open.addEventListener("click", addChild, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/AhCgd/)

Answer (score 1):

Creation is easy:
 `var new_div = document.createElement("div");`

Insertion is little more difficult:

```
var your_raphael_container_parent = your_raphael_container.parentNode;
    if (your_raphael_container.nextSibling) {
      your_raphael_container_parent.insertBefore(new_div, your_raphael_container.nextSibling);
    }
    else {
      your_raphael_container_parent.appendChild(new_div);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Cherniv for your help, but I solved the problem as Xotic750 suggested. Cheers!